# Ability to set --no-ff option when merge pull request on TFS

Tags: git, tfs

I have noticed , a fix/patch is made for adding --no-ff option on pull-request merges on TFS

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6073200-no-fastforward-merge-from-pullrequest

But I am unable to find whats that fix/patch version is so that we can apply that  to our existing TFS 2013

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to apply a "patch" to add this to TFS 2013. You'll have to upgrade to whatever version of TFS introduces the feature. TFS 2015 Update 1 is available right now, and Update 2 is currently a release candidate, so it should be launching soon. Given when Microsoft added it to VS Team Services, it may have made the cut for TFS 2015 Update 1 but probably didn't. I don't have an environment I can validate against right now.